# Iterating through a list and outputting it through create_text

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm having some trouble with tkinter's create_text. I'm trying to iterate through a list and have create_text output each item in the list one by one. I can't figure this out, as every time I've tried, it does not work the way I want it to. Here's some code that exemplifies the issue:

```
class GUI(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.c = Canvas(master, width=300, height=300)
        self.c.pack()

    for items in self.test_list:
        items = items

    for i in range(0, 300, 100):
        for j in range(0, 300, 100):
            self.c.create_text(j + 25, i + 20, text=items)

root = Tk()
root.title("Test")
root.geometry("300x300")
GUI(root)
mainloop()
```

Thank you and I appreciate the help.

Comment: What happens and what do you expect?

Comment: When the GUI runs, the number 9 gets repeated 9 times, instead of going through and outputting 1 2 3 4 5..etc.

Here's a picture: https://i.imgur.com/eANdqlF.png

Comment: have you tried some very basic debugging? what happens if you call `print` rather than `create_text`? Does the output surprise you?

Comment: smells like a closure

Comment: Have you tried indenting?  :)  Check that inner loop.

Comment: @reergymerej apologies, I just pasted the code incorrectly. I fixed that.

Comment: @BryanOakley when I do print (items) inside that nested for loop I also get 9 iterations of the number 9.

Comment: It iterates `items` to 9.  The next loops print 9 over and over.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code had severe indentation problems.
Further, you did not call `mainloop` on any object.
Then, the position of the objects on the canvas was outside the visible window:

I fixed the code so it runs, and displays something on the canvas; from there, you can modify it to suit your needs.

```
import tkinter as tk


class GUI(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.test_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
        self.c = tk.Canvas(master, width=300, height=300)
        self.c.pack()

        for idx, elt in enumerate(self.test_list):
            row = (idx // 3 + 5) * 20
            col = (idx % 3 + 5) * 20

            self.c.create_text(row, col, text=elt)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Test")
    root.geometry("300x300")
    GUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ah, I thought I fixed the code I pasted but the indents aren't actually like that in my IDE..I'll blame it on my lack of sleep. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This has two outer loops.

```
# iterates, items == 9 now
for items in self.test_list:
    items = items


# uses 9 over and over
for i in range(0, 300, 100):
    for j in range(0, 300, 100):
        self.c.create_text(j + 25, i + 20, text=items)
```

Maybe try this instead.

```
for items in self.test_list:
    for i in range(0, 300, 100):
        for j in range(0, 300, 100):
            self.c.create_text(j + 25, i + 20, text=items)
```